# variablesPerSplit default value rounding in smileRandomForest()

Tags: random-forest, implementation

I have used the Google Earth Engine's smileRandomForest() classifier and leaving the variablesPerSplit to the default value sqrt(N_variables) with N_variables=8 input variables, which I think is appropriate to limit the risk of overfitting (based on variablesPerSplit << N_variables) but I would like to know if that is set to 2 or 3 to report it correctly (without having to redo the analysis). Does someone know or can point me to the code itself so I can see what the variable is set to?

Comment: Using the [classifier.explain()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-explain#examples) you can see the details of the parameters including variablesPerSplit utilized by the classifier.

Comment: the method .explain() tells me the details of the trained models as far as I can see: the split in each tree nodes and associated purity etc. I do not see where it reports the hyperparamters of the model

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. The explain() only shows the numberofTrees parameter (which is required for the smileRandomForest()) but not others. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-smilerandomforest) here shows that the default values if unspecified. GEE has some limitations; there may not be any functions to get the parameters othe than ntrees.